# How to test server side validation in AngularJS applications

Tags: angularjs, spring, selenium, testing

I'm developing a Spring + AngularJS 1.x application. For test automation, I'm thinking to use a functional testing tool like Selenium.

Client side form validation can be easily tested using the tool. But I was wondering how to test server side validation. If AngularJS had some setting, using which client side validation could be disabled, then my same test scripts could be used for server side testing. Otherwise, I think I'll have to write server test scripts using a separate, API testing tool. Not only will that double the effort, but also I 'll have to simulate using CORS, CSRF etc., which might not be a great reality-check.

Like to hear recommendations.

(Note: In AngularJS, if we submit the form even if client side errors are displayed, AngularJS does not populate the fields)

Comment: Your testing two completely different things, that just happen to share some data.  Write some JUnit tests or whatever you use to test Spring apps.  The server shouldn't care about your client tests, and your client tests shouldn't care about the server (you should be mocking the server).

Comment: But, I think that testing it as a whole application in stead of two different thing, it would spare me of repeating many test cases in the server side. Also, being closer to reality, it will be more error-proof. It would be great if AngularJS would support disabling validations, I think.

Comment: You think you're going to save yourself time, but you'll just end up complicating your testing environment, and make it harder to decypher where problems are actually occurring.  When I write tests for client-side code, I want them to run each time I make change, giving me real-time feedback - having the server involved will likely slow you down.  What if you want to test latency of a request?  What if someone joins the team who knows nothing about Spring, but requires a complete stack, just to perform client-side tests?

Comment: I see, but then we don't need exhaustive end-to-end system testing? Or you mean we need all of them: client, server and system testing?

Comment: In a full e2e test, it's difficult to mock the database or a third party service being unavailable, or someone fiddling with some JSON, whereas creating high quality unit tests makes it very easy to fake/mock a very wide variety of scenarios.  In short, yes, all of the above.  In our team, the head tester builds various Selenium scripts to check each product scenario, but he won't be checking that a log gets written when a database connection fails, that's down to my unit test, so in that sense it won't be exhaustive, just reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, e2e tests will not be adequate for many scenarios like you describe above. But, I was wondering just about validation test cases -- if those could be reused for server side testing. Validation test cases are huge and so I was thinking to spare my Java developers writing unit tests for those, if AngularJS provided the feature discussed above.

Comment: I can't see how this would work in a continuous integration scenario.

Comment: I was imagining something like this: 1) The application will provide some way to switch ON/OFF client validation (Say as a request parameter: http://test.example.com/?client-validation=OFF) 2) Selenium will first run the validation test cases with client validation ON 3) Selenium will repeat the test cases with client validation OFF

Comment: And this code would be in production?  You *really* need to right some Java unit tests - don't trust anything the client gives you.  I can't really add much else to than to strongly discourage the approach your taking.

Comment: Not in production. I was thinking in the testing phase of the CI, when selenium would run. For example, in the integration testing phase in maven. Or, in a separate test server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can disable **client side validation** with some hacking methods like so :

first you need to use `JavascriptExecutor` 
and write a function to remove `required`  attribute from your element(s)

```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById("city").required = false;");
```

after running this code your client side validation will disabled , and all validations are coming from server side .

Comment: Looks like a way. Thanks, Hasan.